# Clicking on dialogue box options using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was just wondering how is it possible to  click on the options of dialogue boxes using python? I want to write a python code to click the 'Subscribe' button automatically(as shown in the picture link) . What modules should I look into?
Thanks! https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHCSA.png

Comment: If that's a website, you could look into WebDriver. That's an API for remote controlling browsers.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak  Sorry, but that is a program running in my system.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure there is a way to do that in Python. There's Sikuli (http://www.sikuli.org/) though, which is a screen-based automation tool.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Thank-You. Sikuli (sikuli.org) looks interesting. Will look into it.